# Does merge model can work with light data migration?

Tags: iphone, core-data, migration

This problem bothers me a lot and try to get some help.I knew this is a old one but I still don't find the solution.

In my application, I try to use modelByMergingModels to gather all my data models into one, then pass to the persistentStoreCoordinator. Everything is fine until I need to implement the data migration just in case the data model will be changed in the future.

Here are the steps I did.
1. Design-Add modal version to create a new data
2. Add a new attribute,SAVE
3. Add the light data migration options dictionary to addPersistentStoreWithType method
4. Run the programs and get the error. "Can't find model for source store";

However, if I change my managedObjectModel accessor to init only one data model and get rid of the modelByMergeingModels or mergedModelFromBundles. It just works.

So my question is, does data migration works when I use merge models or mergedModelFromBundles?

What's the best way if I have multiple data models and try to implement the data migration.

Hope the question make sense. Many thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a bug in Core Data. Please open a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com so that Apple will know more people are having this problem.

As for a workaround, I am not aware of one, however you may try migrating the models individually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try to migrate the model individually.

Answer (score 0):

Merging models does not work with lightweight data migration.

From the Apple Docs:

> To perform automatic lightweight migration, Core Data needs to be able to **find the source** and destination managed object **model**s itself **at runtime**.

If you use `+modelByMergeingModels:` than that is used for the destination model. However Core Data will not be able to find source model. Source model has been created using `+modelByMergeingModels:` in older version of the application and Core Data does try to merge models to find out the source model.

What I ended up doing is that I have (manually) created a new merged `.xcdatamodeld` by editing the XML files of the models, added it into the project, removed the separate `.xcdatamodeld`s from Compile Sources and instead of using `+modelByMergeingModels:` use `NSManagedObjectModel`'s `-initWithContentsOfURL:` with the URL of the new merged model. I'll probably create a script that will automatically merge the models in the future.